# Advice on datastructure

Tags: c#, wpf, data-structures

I was looking for some advice on what options are possible to create an interactive table similar to the image below with C#4.0 WPF.

Essentially I want some fixed data displayed on the left and based on user input the remaining data recalcs based based on selections

I was thinking a datatable has about 95% of the functionality I need but I can't find many resources or info on adding controls to make it interactive or if what I'm considering is a dead-end.

I've currently got new datatables being generated based on selections elsewhere and displayed in Winforms DataGridView but it makes it difficult to compare so I really wanted to make it more interactive. For WPF I'd hoped there would be something nicer.

[image]

My questions are, can a datatable do this? Are there any better alternatives?

Additional Info:

- The data doesn't come from a database, or a single source.
- It doesn't need to be saved anywhere either
- The columns and rows are not fixed

Comment: A `DataTable` is not a Control. It doesn't show anything.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - you're right. I've currently been mocking up the backend structure with Winforms and have used a DataGridView to display the DataTables. I've updated my Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataGrid` can of course do this for you, similar to WinForms DataGridView.

For the backend you have many choices but to accommodate runtime flexibility the good old DataTable might still be a good choice.

Probably link it through a `CollectionViewSource`